# $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega} d\omega$, integrating complex exponential

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

$$I=\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j\omega} e^{j \omega t}~d\omega\tag{1}$$

By euler's indentity:

$$I = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j\omega}\Big(\cos(\omega t) + j \sin(\omega t)\Big)~d\omega\tag{2}$$

$$I = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{1}{j\omega}\cos(\omega t) + \frac{1}{j\omega}j \sin(\omega t)\Big)~d\omega\tag{3}$$

$$I = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{1}{j\omega}\cos(\omega t) + \frac{1}{\omega} \sin(\omega t)\Big)~d\omega\tag{4}$$

$$I = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\omega t)}{j\omega} d\omega + \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\omega} \Big)~d\omega\tag{5}$$

$$I = -j \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega} d\omega + \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\omega} \Big)~d\omega\tag{6}$$

$$I=\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\omega} d\omega\tag{7}$$

going from (5) to (6), why does the cosine term equal zero?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the author means the integrated is an odd function ($\cos(-\omega t)/(-\omega)=-\cos(\omega t)/\omega$ so from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ the integral is zero. However I would be suspicious of a calculation that manipulates integrals of non-integrable functions.

Comment: how do you know its odd?... cosine is even but $\omega$ is odd...  is even divided by odd, odd?

Comment: Correct: $f(-x)/g(-x)=f(x)/(-g(x))=-f(x)/g(x)$ if $f$ is even and $g$ is odd.